# cannot access properties openERP

Tags: odoo

I'm new to OpenERP, I have problem accessing properties (fields) of object/record:

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context={}, toolbar=False):
    result = super(extended_shipments_wz, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id, view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar)
    shipment_id = self._get_active_id(cr, uid, view_id, context)
    shipment_obj = self.pool.get('stock.picking.in').browse(cr, uid, shipment_id)
   #some more code 
   #shipment_obj.origin, etc... fails
   return result
```

shipment_id gives me correct ID. shipment_obj is returned (not null) when I try to access any shipment_obj properties (just for testing) it gives me error:

```
LINE 1: ...ng.id FROM "stock_picking" WHERE stock_picking.id IN (false)... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: can you check in context what are the values you are getting ? whether you are getting active_id same as shipment_id.

Comment: {u'lang': u'en_US', u'tz': False, u'uid': 1, u'active_model': u'stock.picking.in', u'default_type': u'in', u'contact_display': u'partner_address', u'search_disable_custom_filters': True, u'active_ids': [1], u'active_id': 1}

Comment: active_id is the correct ID

Comment: try `shipment_obj = self.pool.get('stock.picking').browse(cr, uid, active_id)`

Comment: Thanks for response and I will try this. I'm new to OpenERP, can you please explain why I should refer to 'stock.picking' instead of 'stock.picking.in'?

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but getting same result.

Comment: {'_model': <openerp.osv.orm.stock.picking object at 0x045C92B0>, '_table_name': 'stock.picking', '_id': 14, '_context': {u'lang': u'en_US', u'tz': False, u'uid': 1, u'active_model': u'stock.picking.in', u'default_type': u'in', u'contact_display': u'partner_address', u'search_disable_custom_filters': True, u'active_ids': [14], u'active_id': 14}, '_cr': <openerp.sql_db.Cursor object at 0x046A9CB0>, '_uid': 1, '_fields_process': {}, '_cache': {'stock.picking': {14: {'id': 14}}},

Comment: '_data': {14: {'id': 14}}, '_table': <openerp.osv.orm.stock.picking object at 0x045C92B0>, '_list_class': <class 'openerp.osv.orm.browse_record_list'>, '_browse_record__logger': <logging.Logger instance at 0x046B3738>}